# PowerShell wait for function call to complete

Tags: powershell

I am calling a series of PowerShell functions from a master script (each function is a test).
I specify the tests in an XML file and I want them to run in order.

The functions to call are organized in PowerShell module files (.psm1). The master script calls Import-Module as needed and then calls the function via something like this...

```
$newResults = & "$runFunction" @ARGS
```

or this...

```
$newResults = Invoke-Expression $runFunctionWithArgs
```

I have gotten both to work just fine and the XML file parsing invokes these commands in the correct order.

**Problem:** The tests are apparently launched asynchronously so that the first test I launch does not necessarily get invoked and complete before the second test is invoked.

Note, the tests are functions in a PowerShell module and not commands so I do not think that Start-Process will work (but please tell me if you know how to make that work).

**More Details:**
It would take too much to add all the code, but essentially what each function call does is create a hashtable with one or more "TestResult" objects. "TestResult" has things like Success codes and a TimeStamp. Each test does things that take different amounts of time, but all synchronous. I would expect the timestamps to be the same order that I called each test, especially since the first thing each test does is get the timestamp so it should not depend on what the test does. When I run in the ISE, everything goes in order. When I run in the command window, the timestamps do not match my expected order.

**Workaround:**
My working theory is still that PowerShell is somehow parallelizing the calls. I can get consistent results by making the invocation of each call dependent on the results of the previous call. It is a dummy check because I know that what I test will always be true, but PowerShell doesn't know that

```
if ($newResults.Count -ne [Long]::MaxValue) { $newResults = & "$runFunction" @ARGS }
```

PowerShell thinks that it needs to know if the previous call count is not MaxValue.

Comment: The way you are invoking is synchronous.  It would appear that something within $runFunction is causing the async behavior. Can't tell what that is, unless you show us the script.

Comment: It would take too much to add all the script, but here in essence:

Comment: Somewhere down in your script are you using `Start-Process`?  By default it doesn't wait for the process to exit unless you use the `-Wait` parameter.  Other things that can cause async execution: Start-Job, Invoke-Command -AsJob, executing a windows subsystem executable i.e. C:\PS> notepad.exe, Invoke-Item, Workflow parallel and foreach -parallel.